# What is the answer on?

Tags: cipher

```
x = r("k")
y = l("ft")
z = x("t")

The answer is on the x(y(z("i36g9q4e")))
```

hint

> = dl("u9j6")

Comment: That was really neat!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> keyboard

because the functions are defined as

> r() = right on the keyboard
>  l() = left on the keyboard
>  d() = down on the keyboard (u() presumably equals up but is not used)

thus we get

> x = r('k') == l, so x is left
>  y = l('ft') == dr, so y is down then right
>  z = x('t') == r (see two lines up), so z is right

and finally the hint

> is just down and left from u9j6 on the keyboard (ie u->h, 9->i, j->n, 6->t)

whence

> z('i36g9q4e') -> o47h0w5r, y('o47h0w5r) -> lrunpstf, x('lrunpstf') -> keyboard!

Comment: You got it, well done!